# How to index items from higher dimensions in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I've done some search on this site but it seems there is no similar question (or my description is too bad to search).

I'm facing a problem that I need to fetch some ndarray from a multi-dimensional ndarray in numpy.

Suppose I have

```
W = np.random.randn(2,2,3,8)
```

which represents eight 2x2x3 filters in a convolutional layers in a CNN.

I want to access the first filter, which is the first 2x2x3 in W.

I tried

```
 print(W.shape)
 print(W[:,:,:,:c].shape)
 print(W[:,:,:,:c])
 print(W[:,:,:,:c].flatten())
```

where c is in range 0 - 7. The result returned is always

```
(2, 2, 3, 8)
(2, 2, 3, 0)
[]
[]
```

But I expect to see the 2x2x3 filter result from above indexing..

from the above 4 lines of code...

Reproduction:

```
W = np.random.randn(2,2,3,8)
for c in range(0, 8):
#   print(W.shape)
    print(W[:,:,:,:c].shape)
#   print(W[:,:,:,:c])
#   print(W[:,:,:,:c].flatten())
```

The result is:

```
(2, 2, 3, 0)
(2, 2, 3, 1)
(2, 2, 3, 2)
(2, 2, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 2, 3, 5)
(2, 2, 3, 6)
(2, 2, 3, 7)
```

where I actually expect 8 (2, 2, 3).
Please help!

Comment: Try : `W[...,0]`.

Comment: A HERO @Divakar

Comment: @Divakar would you please also explain why my method doesn't work in the answer? if you have time... Thank you

Comment: What's your `c`? If you had tried with `c=1`, should have worked but with one singleton dim.

Comment: @Divakar it's the channel index. 3 matches the current (input) depth of the image, 8 is the output depth for this layer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are seeing, but then, I can't really try out what you are doing since you don't provide `c`

Comment: c is in range 0 to 7. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Right, that isn't a reproducible example. Going by a generous interpretation: `for c in range(0, 7): <your code>` I cannot reproduce your example, I get exactly what I would expect to print.... please see how to create a [mcve] ... in particular, pay attention to the "complete" aspect.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga question description edited !

Answer (score 1):

You can access your filters by slicing `W`

```
import numpy as np

W = np.random.randn(2,2,3,8)
for c in range(0, 8):
    print(W[:,:,:,c].shape)
    print(W[:,:,:,c])
```

Basically, `W[:,:,:,0]` is your first filter and so on.